# Python: объединение функций

Tags: python, функции, selenium

У меня есть очень много однообразных функций, которые отличаются двумя значениями. Я хочу написать одну универсальную функцию, в которую можно подставлять любое значение.

```
def fillDeviceUIDForm(driver, deviceuid=test_defaults.DEVICE_UID):
    mainPage = MainPageClass(driver)
    mainPage.deviceUID.sendKeys(deviceuid)

def fillDeviceConfigForm(driver, devconfname=test_defaults.DEVICE_CONF_NAME):
    mainPage = MainPageClass(driver)
    mainPage.deviceConfigurationName.sendKeys(devconfname)
```

В этих функциях `deviceUID` и `deviceConfigurationName` - это поля которые содержат xPath, а `deviceuid` и `devconfname` - это значения, которые подставляются в эти поля соответственно. Я думал создать функцию наподобе:

```
def fillAnyForm(driver, fieldForm, valueForm):
    mainPage = MainPageClass(driver)
    mainPage.FindXpath(fieldForm)
    mainPage.Fill.sendKeys(valueForm)
```

Но не могу разобраться с этими переменными, у меня есть внешний файл который называется `test_defaults` в котором находятся все значения, которые я подставляю. А также в другом файле у меня есть описание всех элементов на сайте с их `xPath`.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```py
def fill_form(main_page, dev_name, values):
    attr = getattr(main_page, dev_name)
    # attr().sendKeys(values)
    attr.sendKeys(values)
```

примеры вызова:

```
fill_form(main_page, "deviceUID", test_defaults.DEVICE_UID)
fill_form(main_page, "deviceConfigurationName", test_defaults.DEVICE_CONF_NAME)
```

Comment: получилось так: ```def fillForm(driver, field, values):
    attr = getattr(driver, field)
    attr().sendKeys(values)```

Comment: а в основном коде вызываю функцию с подстановкой своих данных так: `          middleLevelFunctions.fillForm(
                self.driver,
                field=mainPageObject.deviceUID,
                values=test_defaults.DEVICE_UID
            )`

Comment: Хотя нет, оно не заработало, но очень близко...